# money withdrawl function '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started to learn python. I have encounter the following error
**'<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'**
When the balance reached 0 it shows 'You have not enough money' but when I re-run it. I will have error and I don't know how to fix it.

```
current_bal = 100

def withdrawl(balance, amount):
    if balance < amount:
        print('You have not enough money')
    else:
        balance -= amount
        print('You have withdrawn {}. Your new balance is {}'.format(amount, balance))
        return balance

current_bal = withdrawl(current_bal, 100)
```

Comment: Because you don’t return anything on the if statement, `current_bal` ends up nothing.

Comment: you need to return `balance` even if `balance` is less than `amount`, otherwise you will set `current_bal` to `None` as your if statement return nothing. Then, `None` < `amount` raise error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when `balance < amount`, You return nothing, and `current_bal` is equal to `None`. you can't use `<` between `NoneType` and `int`. You can try this:

````
current_bal = 100

def withdrawl(balance, amount):
    if balance < amount:
        print('You have not enough money')
    else:
        balance -= amount
        print('You have withdrawn {}. Your new balance is {}'.format(amount, balance))
    return balance

current_bal = withdrawl(current_bal, 100)```
````